# How can I start Android Setting > Display > Screen > Screen Scale screen programatically?

Tags: android

It is starting Display option. I want to go further inside Display.

```
  startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that is not supported.